# React Native View Shot

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-view-shot for taking snap shot.
In that I am passing React native view in captureRef method.
Now in my view there are multiple Animated.Views so I am getting error of The content size must not be zero or negative. Got: (0, 0).

Please help me if anyone have idea for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

Make sure that the component inside the **ViewShot** has in style

```
width: 200, or '100%'
height: 200, or '100%'
```